# Can't Hold a Negative Value in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, negative-number

I have a project where I need to input numbers between -25 and 25 and count how many times each was inputted. The code I have only accepts positive numbers. Line 26 and 39 give me problems and I can't get my amount array to hold any negative numbers.

My code:

```
public class PP62{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char response = 'a';
        int numbers[] = new int[100], count, amount[] = new int[100], n2;
        count = 0;

        do{

        if((response == 'y')||(response == 'Y')||(count == 0)){

            count++;

            System.out.println("Enter in an integer between -25 and 25.");
            do{
            numbers[count] = SavitchIn.readLineInt();

            if((numbers[count] > 25)||(numbers[count] < -25)){
                System.out.println("Error, Invalid Input. Re-Enter integer between -25 and 25.");
            }

            else if((numbers[count] <= 25)||(numbers[count] >= -25)){
                n2 = numbers[count];
                amount[n2]++;
            }

            }while((numbers[count] > 25)||(numbers[count] < -25));

            System.out.println("Enter in another integer? (Y/N)");
            response = SavitchIn.readLineNonwhiteChar();
        }

        else if ((response == 'n')||(response == 'N')){

            for(int a = -25; a <= 25; a++){
                System.out.println(a + "'s entered: ");
                System.out.println(amount[a] + "\n");
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }

        else{
            System.out.println("Incorrect Input. Must be 'Y' (yes) or 'N' (no).");
            response = SavitchIn.readLineNonwhiteChar();
        }}while(count > 0);
    }   
}
```

Comment: where is the line 26 and 39?

Comment: Line 26:  amount[n2]++; -  (in the first else if statement)                                         Line 39: System.out.println(amount[a] + "\n");   - (in the for loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

array indexes in java cannot be negative, so you need to fix them starting from 0

like this:

```
char response = 0;
int numbers[] = new int[51];

do
{
    System.out.println("Enter in an integer between -25 and 25.");
    int n = SavitchIn.readLineInt();
    if( (n > 25) || (n < -25))
        System.out.println("Error, Invalid Input. Re-Enter integer between -25 and 25.");
    else
        numbers[n+25]++;

    System.out.println("Enter in another integer? (Y/N)");
    do
    {
        response = SavitchIn.readLineNonwhiteChar();
        if ( (Character.toLowerCase(response) != 'y') && (Character.toLowerCase(response) != 'n') )
            System.out.println("Incorrect Input. Must be 'Y' (yes) or 'N' (no).");
    } while ( (Character.toLowerCase(response) != 'y') && (Character.toLowerCase(response) != 'n') );
} while (Character.toLowerCase(response) == 'y');

for(int a = -25; a <= 25; a++)
    System.out.println(a + "'s entered: " + numbers[25+a] + " times\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
else if((numbers[count] <= 25)||(numbers[count] >= -25)){
                n2 = numbers[count];
                amount[n2]++;
            }
```

What if `n2 = numbers[count] = -25` ? `n2` will be negative and `amount[n2]++` accessing array with negative index. You can't access an array with negative index, doing so will result in `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Why don't we use an array with size `50` and count with `a[n2+25]++` instead!

Answer (score -1):

I can't test the code since I don't have the SavitchIn class, but I note that the line

```
amount[n2]++;
```

will at some point try to index an array with a negative number.  Array indexes go from 0 on up.  I would recommend

```
amount[n2+25]++;
```

and then

```
System.out.println(amount[a-25]+"\n");
```

on the display.  That is, shift the numbers you want to represent (-25..25) to a range the array can handle (0..50).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Helped me out a lot, but when outputting you would need to + 25, not subtract.